# Hide buttons when textfield equals nil and show when not nil

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

With my code the buttons are hiding when the viewcontroller is showing because the textfields are empty. The buttons should however show when the textfields are not empty anymore. The buttons are not showing with my code - what am I doing wrong?

```
let allInputValues = nameInput.text! + middleInput.text! + surnameInput.text!

        if allInputValues == "" {
            nextButton.hidden = true
            finishButton.hidden = true
        } else {
            nextButton.hidden = false
            finishButton.hidden = false
        }
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: Where is the code you posted?

Comment: When does the above code execute? Not really enough code for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your view controller as a textField delegate. Then use `textFieldDidEndEditing()` for each textField to run your check and either keep the button hidden or show the button.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nextButton.hidden = true
        finishButton.hidden = true

        nameInput.delegate = self
        middleInput.delegate = self
        surnameInput.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        let allInputValues = nameInput.text! + middleInput.text! + surnameInput.text!

        if allInputValues == "" {
            nextButton.hidden = true
            finishButton.hidden = true
        } else {
            nextButton.hidden = false
            finishButton.hidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Swift 3**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nextButton.isHidden = true
        finishButton.isHidden = true

        nameInput.delegate = self
        middleInput.delegate = self
        surnameInput.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        let allInputValues = nameInput.text! + middleInput.text! + surnameInput.text!

        if allInputValues == "" {
            nextButton.isHidden = true
            finishButton.isHidden = true
        } else {
            nextButton.isHidden = false
            finishButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added all of your code, both the UITextFieldDelegate, the delegates within viewDidLoad and the function after viewDidLoad, but without any luck. The buttons are still visible when the textfields are empty.

Comment: @D.Finna Try my edit to start with the buttons hidden

Answer (score 0):

You are only running the "if" once, at the start of the program. Place it into a loop that runs it each time the values change.